# Nav bar will not move up to be even with the img at the top using CSS dreamweaver

Tags: css, web, dreamweaver

I have a logo image on the upper left side of the site and want my nav to show on the upper right side of the site. The nav is showing on the right side of the page but instead of being parallel to the logo it is below it even thought the logo is on the left side. Any idea what I am missing in the code below that is preventing the nav from moving up.

```
   @charset 'UTF-8';

   html,
   html * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }

   body {
     font-family: arial, sans-serif;
     <!-- font-size: 1vw;>
     background: white;
   }

   img { 
       width: 100%;
       max-width: 100%;
       height: auto;
       vertical-align: middle;
       -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
       transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   }

   a, a:visited {
       color: inherit;
   }

   header {
     position: fixed;
     padding: 1.5em;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
   }

   .site-logo {
       width: 30%;
       max-width: 30%;
       position: relative;
       display: block;
   }

   .site-logo img {
     width: 22em;
   }

   .logo {
     opacity: 1;
   }

   .site-nav {
     position: relative;
     float: right;
     z-index: 400;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     display: block !important;
     width: 68%;
     padding: .75em 1em 0 0;
     opacity: .95;
     background: none;
   }

   .site-nav ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     text-align: right;
   }

   .site-nav ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 1.5em;
   }

   .site-nav ul li a {
     font-size: .85em;
     padding-bottom: .5em;
     text-decoration: none;
     letter-spacing: .15em;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: #000000;
     -webkit-transition: color .3s;
     transition: color .3s;
   }

   .site-nav ul li a:hover {
     outline: none;
     border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   }
```

HTML

```
    <header>
    <!-- Logo -->
        <a class="site-logo">
            <img class="logo" src="images/SBI Logo.png" alt=""/>
        </a>

    <!-- Navigation Menu -->    
          <nav class="site-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Rooms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gift Certificates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Things To Do</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

            </ul>
          </nav>
    </header>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN8lC.png)

Comment: You will need to post the HTML also : )

Comment: Oops! :) Done!!

Comment: I tried that and removing the padding just moves the logo to the very top of the page but the nav still remains below the logo. It's strange as it makes no sense to me why it will not move up.

Comment: Changed .site-logo img width to 100% and added display: block but nothing changed.

Comment: How do I post and example? I'm new on this site and I don't see a way to attach and image?

Comment: Use the snippet tool when writing the question body (Ctrl-M)

Comment: Ok I added an image of the dreamweaver screen. It appears the same way when live except the mean is horizontal instead of vertical. But you can see where the nav is appears below the logo.

Comment: Your nav does not move up because it RELATIVE to the previous element, the IMAGE is styled as BLOCK element therefore your nav appears just below the bottom of the image. also do NOT use html commenting in style sheet you should use /* comment */ instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting bogged down in the style sheet and using EM too, it would be much easier for you to use PIXELS instead of EM to position your elements.

```
<style>
    .mysitelogo
    {
      margin-top: 16px;
      width: 458px;
      height: 114px;
    }
    .mysitenav
    {
      float: right;
      padding: 8px;
      opacity: .95;
    }
  </style>


  <header>
    <!-- Logo -->
    <img class="mysitelogo" src="logo.gif" alt="" />
    <!-- Navigation Menu -->
    <nav class="mysitenav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rooms</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gift Certificates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Things To Do</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Using the code above you can get the layout you desire, THEN fine tune your layout in the stylesheet.

Some times it is easier to break the bigger problem down into basic parts.

Read this page for better understanding of using EM which is relative to FONT SIZE 
https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp